# Submersion Theorem for manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary

I've got a question about a lemma in Milnors "TOPOLOGY FROM THE DIFFERENTIABLE VIEWPOINT".

LEMMA 4: If $y\in N$ is a regular value, both for $f$ and for the restriction $f|_{\partial X}$, then $f^{-1}(y)\subset X$ is a smooth $m-n$-manifold with boundary. Furthermore the boundary $\partial (f^{-1}(y))$ is precisely equal to the intersection of $f^{-1}(y)$ with $\partial X$

Maybe this lemma can be called Submersion Theorem for manifold with boundary.
So, I want to find a example and take $X=D^2$, $N=\mathbb{R}$ and $f^{-1}(y)$ should be $D^1$. $D^n$ is the unit disk. But I am not able to find the explicit function $f$ and the $y$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What about projection??

Comment: So, you mean $f:D^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\;(x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_1$?
But what is $y\in\mathbb{R}$ to get $D^1=f^{-1}(y)$?

Comment: Think... ${}{}{}{}{$

Comment: Ah, okay. $D^1=\{x_1\in\mathbb{R}\;|\;1-{x_1}^2\geq0\}$, so $y$ has to be 0, right? Because $f^{-1}(0)$ are the $(x_1,x_2)$ with $x_1=0$ and $-1\leq x_2\leq 1$

Comment: What is $D^1$?? Read the theorem and think properly...

Comment: So, I worte it before, didnt I? $D^1=\{x_1\in\mathbb{R}\;|\;1-{x_1}^2\geq 0\}$.

Comment: You have to define $D^1$ as a subset of $D^2\subset\Bbb R^2$. Are you not meaning the subset $y=0$?

Comment: Ok, thats right. So I define $D^1$ this way: $D^1=\{(x_1,x_2)\in D^2\;|\; x_2=0\}$. And..I think $y$ has to be a value in $\mathbb{R}$ and not a subset.